# Disable/hide submit button after countdown timer finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I am using `jquery.countdown.min.js` plugin. Below are the javascript code from webpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#example').countdown({
            date: '06/06/2015 10:16:59',
            offset: -8,
            day: 'Day',
            days: 'Days'
        }, function () {
            alert('Done!');
        });
    </script>
```

At the moment i
There is a form on webpage along with Submit button. I want to hide/disable submit button.

Can you please advise me how to fulfill this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable the button when the countdown is done?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable or hide the button. Both are same for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) like

```
$('#example').countdown({
            date: '06/06/2015 10:16:59',
            offset: -8,
            day: 'Day',
            days: 'Days'
        }, function () {
            $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
            //or $('[type="submit"]').hide();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test and let you know. Voted up.

Comment: @404, no. [type="submit"] is saying -> the attribute `type` equals `submit`

Comment: @404, there are other ways you can target the button like putting a class or id for the button

Comment: got it thanks. One more thing if i hide submit button, is it possible to display some text there?

Comment: @404, sorry just got back. Do you mean display a different element with text in place of where the button was?

Comment: Thanks. I find out how to put text between that.